# Button won't show up

Tags: java, button

Why doesn't my button show up? I tried everything I can think of. Can anyone spot what I did wrong?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Object rowData[][] = {{"Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3"},
          {"Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3"}};
Object columnNames[] = {"Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three"};
JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));

JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
quitButton.setBounds(50, 60, 80, 30);
add(quitButton);
table.setEnabled(false);
table.setBounds(0, 100, 100, 100);

table.setAlignmentY(BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(600, 600);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setLocation(400, 100);
```

Comment: Have you added your button in JTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding your button to the `JFrame` at all. You're just calling `add(quitButton)`, which means you're invoking it on whatever object contains this method, not on the frame.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer but could You tell me why i cant change my table position in frame, its always take all space . I tried : table.setBounds(0, 100, 100, 100);- dont work || table.getMaximumSize();           - i cant use it for some reason

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add your Button to the ContentPane.

Comment: The above *is* an answer. Granted it could be a little more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

presuming you use an IDE which has specific support for java.swing.* like netbeans or whatever, you could just use their built in tools to use it, which prevents this kind of errors.